# Linux apt-get update I get "unmet dependency error" Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Why I am not able to install a few packages in my Ubuntu 16.04

If i try:  `sudo apt-get install update`  i get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
y-ppa-manager : Depends: yad (>= 0.36.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libnotify-bin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: ppa-purge but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xterm
             Depends: launchpad-getkeys (>= 0.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: python-appindicator but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: python-gtk2 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: xclip but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: gksu but it is not going to be installed or
                         kdesudo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried:   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager`

But no use.

Please suggest.

Comment: did you do `apt-get -f install` as instructed by terminal?

Comment: i get same error after using -f option

Comment: please try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-cache policy linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic`?

Comment: This is the output:    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0-64.85
  Candidate: 4.4.0-64.85
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0-64.85 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Upgrade your system as montionned @George then run `sudo aptitude -f install`

Answer (score 2):

The most basic fix to resolve dependencies problems is to run:

```bsh
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The `-f` is short for `--fix-broken`. This will attempt to correct broken dependencies. If you manually installed a package that had unmet dependencies, `apt-get` will install those dependencies if possible, otherwise it may simply remove the package that you installed in order to resolve the problem.

Go ahead and run:

```bsh
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then run this again:

```bsh
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If you still get the same error, remove and add the repository you just added.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: For the command :  sudo apt-get -f install  i get,     Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)    Also i get ,         cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-64-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-64-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)

Comment: For freeing up some space in /home directory i tried:  sudo dpkg -P linux-image{,-extra}-4.4.0-{43,45,47,51}-generic

Comment: No space left on device.... Looks like your running out of space. Try freeing up some more space.. perhaps move some files to external or extra partition

Comment: Yes tried removing some kernels, now /home space shows from 100% used to 60 % used and pls confirm if i remove some kernels listed in dpkg -l | grep -G "linux.*image.*" -h, should not affect anything right?

Comment: try running the **sudo apt-get -f install** again

Comment: Removing the kernels doesnt affect anything right? and also how do i know which kernel to remove and which to keep for freeing up the /home directory

Comment: Check for the current version of kernel your running.. Dont remove the corresponding version. **uname -a** or **uname -r**

Answer (score 1):

Begin by Removing Partially Installed Packages with Unmet Dependencies

So, If you run into dependency issues while installing a package, and then want to remove the partially installed package, follow the process below:

Run an audit to show packages with unmet dependencies: 
`dpkg --audit` OR `sudo dpkg --audit`

Force remove offending package(s): `dpkg --remove --force-all [name of package]`

After that, run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Finally repeat `sudo apt-get -f install`

At this point, output should be

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded

Now you can `sudo apt-get update` and your machine should be back to normal.